# How to solve NoMethodError using Ruby on Rails 3

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-3

Actually I want to display all data of Magazine model on the admin side page But i got the following error while tried to fetch all data on the admin side(i.e.http://localhost:3000/homes/magazineissue).I also want to display some value belongs to User model through user's id.

## Error:

```
NoMethodError in HomesController#magazineissue

undefined method `user_id' for #<Array:0x2780b98>
Rails.root: C:/Site/library_management1

Application Trace | Framework Trace | Full Trace
app/controllers/homes_controller.rb:100:in `magazineissue'
```

My codes are as follows.

## views/homes/magazineissue.html.erb:

```
<% if admin_signed_in? %>
<div class="bar">
  Logged in as <strong><%= current_admin.email %></strong>.
  <%= link_to 'Edit profile', edit_admin_registration_path, :class => 'navbar-link' %> |
  <%= link_to "Logout", destroy_admin_session_path, method: :delete, :class => 'navbar-link'  %>
</div>
<% else %>
  <%= link_to "Sign up", new_admin_registration_path, :class => 'navbar-link'  %> |
  <%= link_to "Login", new_admin_session_path, :class => 'navbar-link'  %>
<% end %>
<div class="big-container">
<div class="admin-image">
 <div class="bpaddingdiv1"><img src="/assets/admin.png" border="0" name="admin" /></div>
</div>
<div class="borderlightgreen"></div>
<div class="admin-name">
<div class="tpaddingdiv2 textaligncenterdiv"><img src="/assets/adminpanel.png" border="0" name="admin" /></div>
</div>
<div class="leftside">
<div id="leftsidebtn">
 <ul>
<li><a href="/homes/managebooks">Manage Books</a></li>
<li><a href="/homes/userissues" >User Issues</a></li>
<li><a href="/homes/magazineissue" >Magazine Issues</a></li>
 </ul>  
</div>
</div>
<div class="middlebox">
<center>
    <table>
        <thead>
            <tr>
            <th>First Name</th>
            <th>Email Id</th>
            <th>Magazine Name</th>
            <th>Magazine Title</th>
            <th>Purchased on</th>
            <th>CD/DVD</th>
        </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
            <% @magazines.each do |magazine| %>
            <tr>
            <td><%= @users.first_name %></td>
            <td><%= @users.email %></td>
            <td><%= magazine.mag_name %></td>
            <td><%= magazine.mag_title %></td>
            <td><%= magazine.purchased_on %></td>
            <td><%= magazine.cd_dvd %></td>
        </tr>
        <% end %>
        </tbody>
    </table>
</center>
</div>
</div>
```

## views/controller/homes_controller.rb:

```
class HomesController < ApplicationController
     before_filter :authenticate_admin!,only: [:admin]
    def index

    end
    def admin

    end
    def managebooks
        @books=Book.new
        if params[:id]
            @books=Book.find(params[:id])
            @book=Book.all
        end
    end
    def savebooks
        @books=Book.new(params[:books])
        if @books.save
            flash[:notice]="Data has submitted successfully"
            flash[:color]="valid"
            redirect_to :action => 'managebooks',:id => @books.id
        else
            flash[:notice]="Data couldnot submitted successfully"
            flash[:color]="invalid"
            render 'managebooks'
        end
    end
    def remove
        @books=Book.find(params[:id])
        @books.destroy
    end
    def books

    end
    def showbooks
        @books=Book.all
    end
    def searchbooks
        @books=Book.all
    end
    def member
        @users=User.new
    end
    def registration
        @users=User.new
    end
    def savedata
        @users=User.new(params[:users])
        if @users.save
            flash[:notice]="Data has submitted successfully"
            flash[:color]="valid"
            redirect_to :action => 'member'
        else
            flash[:notice]="Data could not submitted successfully"
            flash[:color]="invalid"
            render 'registration'
        end
    end
    def issuebooks
        @issues=Issue.new
    end
    def savedissuebooks
        @issues=Issue.new(params[:issues])
        if @issues.save
            flash[:notice]="information has saved successfully"
            flash[:color]="valid"
            redirect_to :action => 'member'
        else
            flash[:notice]="Data couldnot saved"
            flash[:color]="invalid"
            render 'issuebooks'
        end
    end
    def availablebooks

        @books=Book.all
    end
    def userissues
        @issues=Issue.all
    end
    def magazine
        @magazines=Magazine.new
    end
    def savemagazines
        @users=User.find(params[:id])
        @magazines=Magazine.new(params[:magazines])
        @magazines.user_id=@users.id
        if @magazines.save
            flash[:notice]="Data submitted successfully"
            flash[:color]="valid"
            redirect_to :action => "member"
        else
            flash[:notice]="Data could not saved"
            flash[:color]="invalid"
            render 'magazines'
        end
    end
    def magazineissue
        @magazines=Magazine.all
        @users=User.find(@magazines.user_id)
    end
end
```

## db/migrate/20150317084229_create_magazines.rb

```
class CreateMagazines < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def change
    create_table :magazines do |t|
      t.string :mag_name
      t.boolean :cd_dvd
      t.decimal :cost, :precision => 8, :scale => 2
      t.date :purchased_on
      t.string :mag_title
      t.integer :user_id

      t.timestamps
    end
  end
end
```

## model/magazine.rb

```
class Magazine < ActiveRecord::Base
  attr_accessible :cd_dvd, :cost, :mag_name, :mag_title, :purchased_on
  belongs_to :user
end
```

## model/user.rb

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  attr_accessible :address, :email, :first_name, :last_name, :password, :password_hash, :password_salt, :tel_no ,:password_confirmation
  attr_accessor :password
  before_save :encrypt_password
 EMAIL_REGEX = /\A[A-Z0-9._%+-]+@[A-Z0-9.-]+\.[A-Z]{2,4}\z/i
 validates :email, :presence => true, :uniqueness => true, :format => EMAIL_REGEX
 validates :first_name, :presence => true, :length => {:in => 3..10}
 validates :last_name , :presence => true , :length => {:in => 3..10}
 validates :tel_no , :presence => true , :length => {:in => 1..10}
 validates :password, :confirmation => true
 validates_length_of :password, :in => 6..20, :on => :create
 def self.authenticate(email, password)
    user = find_by_email(email)
    if user && user.password_hash == BCrypt::Engine.hash_secret(password, user.password_salt)
      user
    else
      nil
    end
  end

  def encrypt_password
    if password.present?
      self.password_salt = BCrypt::Engine.generate_salt
      self.password_hash = BCrypt::Engine.hash_secret(password, password_salt)
    end
  end
  has_many :issue
  has_many :book
  has_many :magazine
end
```

Please help me to resolve this error.

Comment: did you do `rake db:migrate`?

Comment: Yes,shivam .When i am doing  @users=User.find(1) instead of  @users=User.find(@magazines.user_id) for testing purpose it is coming properly.But i need the second format(i.e. @users=User.find(@magazines.user_id)) because User model might have many users.

Comment: `@magazines` is an Array. Try `@users=User.find @magazines.first.user_id`

Comment: Thanks Sivam your line helped me..

Comment: thats great. Please accept my answer if it helped. :)

Answer (score 0):

The problem is in controller in line you already mentioned - let's take a look:

```
def magazineissue
    @magazines=Magazine.all
    @users=User.find(@magazines.user_id)
end
```

In here you are fetching an `Array` of `Magazine`s - the `Array` doesn't have an `id` method. What I guess you would like to do is something like:

```
def magazineissue
    @magazines=Magazine.all
    @users=User.find(@magazines.map(&:user_id))
end
```

To fetch `User`s by ALL `Magazine`s.

Let me know if it helped!

**UPDATE**

From the comments we had it looks like you're trying to achieve something like:

```
def magazineissue
    @magazines=Magazine.includes(:user).all
end
```

And in your view, change the `<table>` to:

```
<table>
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>First Name</th>
            <th>Email Id</th>
            <th>Magazine Name</th>
            <th>Magazine Title</th>
            <th>Purchased on</th>
            <th>CD/DVD</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        <% @magazines.each do |magazine| %>
            <tr>
                <td><%= magazine.user.first_name %></td>
                <td><%= magazine.user.email %></td>
                <td><%= magazine.mag_name %></td>
                <td><%= magazine.mag_title %></td>
                <td><%= magazine.purchased_on %></td>
                <td><%= magazine.cd_dvd %></td>
            </tr>
        <% end %>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

Good luck!

Comment: Hi Pawel after adding your line i got the another error and the error is given below.

ERROR:
Showing C:/Site/library_management1/app/views/homes/magazineissue.html.erb where line #44 raised:

undefined method `first_name' for #<Array:0x2e65870>

Comment: @Bapi_agent - So, are you trying to display ALL `Magazine`s, with their `User` info?

Comment: @Bapi_agent - check my updated answer, hope this is what you are thinking about!

Answer (score 0):

As you have defined:

```
@magazines = Magazine.all
```

It results an Array that contains all the magazines.

Now in your HomeController you are doing:

```
@magazines.user_id
```

Which throws:

```
undefined method `user_id' for #<Array:0x2780b98>
```

because as mentioned above `@magazines` is an Array.

Solution to this can be to select a particular `Magazine` object from the returned `@magazines` Array and proceed.

A quick example can be:

```
@users=User.find @magazines.first.user_id
# However this is just for sake of example.
# You may want to select an object from the Array more wisely.
```